# How to do a javascript function for autocomplete with images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I'm trying to do a function that returns a list of search with autocomplete. I have to use a . The final result must be something like this:

http://www.casimages.com.br/i/150325064429419254.png.html

I have done this another autocomplete

html

```
<label class="formee-lbl">
   Região Fiscal
</label>
```

---

Js:

```
               <script type="text/javascript">


                            var availableTags = [
                                 "DFR - SÃO JOSÉ DOS CAMPOS",
                                 "DFR - ARARAGUARA",
                                 "DFR - FRANCA",
                                 "DFR - JUNDIAI",
                                 "DFR - PIRACICABA",
                                 "DFR - BARUERI",
                                 "DERPF - SÃO PAULO",
                                 "DFR - CURITIBA",
                                 "DFR - LONDRINA",
                                 "DFR - CASCAVEL"

                            ];

                            var availableUnidades = [
                                 "UNIDADE: DFR - SÃO JOSÉ DOS CAMPOS",
                                 "UNIDADE: DFR - ARARAGUARA",
                                 "UNIDADE: DFR - FRANCA",
                                 "UNIDADE: DFR - JUNDIAI",
                                 "UNIDADE: DFR - PIRACICABA",
                                 "UNIDADE: DFR - BARUERI",
                                 "UNIDADE: DERPF - SÃO PAULO",
                                 "UNIDADE: DFR - CURITIBA",
                                 "UNIDADE: DFR - LONDRINA",
                                 "UNIDADE: DFR - CASCAVEL"

                            ];

                            $(document).ready(function () {//Carrega a função junto com a página

                               $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                                    source: availableTags
                               });

                               $("#autocompleteUnidades").autocomplete({
                                   source: availableUnidades
                               });


                            });
                   </script>
```

---

What I have to do to add any image to the autocomplete function?
Is there something else I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can write your own renderers

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //...here is the projects source

    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        create: function () {
            $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $('<li>')
                    .append('<a><img src="'+ item.image +'">' + item.label + '<br>' + item.value + '</a>')
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
        }
    });
});
```